Late 80s early 90s teen adventure movie
This is a non animated movie from late 80s - early 90s. The only scene I remember is (most likely) the ending of the movie. 
A gang of kids, various ages (10 to 18), in a war plane that they somehow hijacked or ended up in - I vaguely remember it had a japanese flag on - flying above US territory and as they fly by US fighter planes start following them - for obvious reasons - kids cannot make contact with the US planes so they open this small sun roofy window on the ceiling of the plane, lift up one of the kids who's wearing a Michael Jackson t-shirt, he opens up his shirt/jacket to show it to the pilots and screams "we are Americans" or something similiar. 
The Michael Jackson t-shirt, if I'm not making it up, is white with him and the US flag on, with King of Pop written on it, I think it's from the "Dangerous" era or at least "Bad" that's why I think the movie is set during the time it was filmed. Can't recall faces of the actors. Shouldn't be later than 1995 - I remember most of the movies I watched after that year. I also don't think there were any sci-fi, fantasy motifs, think it was only an action/adventure movie involving kids/teens.

Sounds like The Rescue from 1988, but it wasn't Michael Jackson. The plot:

A team of Navy S.E.A.L.s are sent to destroy a disabled submarine so it will not fall into the wrong hands. They complete their mission, but are captured before they can return to their base. The U.S. government will not mount a rescue mission to free the soldiers, so their adolescent children take over. The kids find a way to venture into the foreign country and then must overcome many obstacles. 

And near the end:

The plane crosses the border back into South Korea. The South Korean base scrambles fighter jets to intercept, fearing the plane is an intruder from the North. Bobby sticks out of the top hatch of the plane and flashes his Bruce Springsteen T-Shirt, identifying the passengers as American to the fighter jets. 

Here's a clip:




I remember watching this as a child. The T-shirt bit stuck with me, as did the secret passage under the table with a cigarette tray glued to it, the one POW strangling a guard through the bars, and a Korean captain choosing to go down with his ship after he realizes it's on a collision course.
